# How can I fix a C# application which is not publishing since changing from Visual Studio 2013 to Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, publishing

I am having a hard time publishing a C# Windows Application to a server. It was working fine while I was on Visual Studio 2013 but once I went to Visual Studio 2015, I get errors that say the proper versions of DLLs did not install in the GAC. And now the application will not work at all.

The error message reads:

> Unable to install or run the application. The application requires that assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.Diagnostics.STrace version 12.0.0.0 be installed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) first

There is a version of the dll in the reference section of the solution. The error message says the one I am using is the wrong version (it says that it needs to install version 12 when the version that I am using is 13).

Comment: Have you tried installing version 12?

Comment: When I got my new computer, it was Windows 10 and would only let me install Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Your application is using old references that aren't included in 15. You either need to update your application to use the new references or install the old ones.

Comment: The error seems pretty clear... You need to reference the dll in your GAC or update the code to use the latest one ^^